# Change status bar color BEFORE deviceready event in Cordova

Tags: cordova

I'm using the `cordova-statusbar` plugin, and I can successfully change the background color of the statusbar using `StatusBar.backgroundColorByHexString` function.

The StatusBar API is obviously not available before `deviceready` event, so when the app starts in my Android device, it actually takes a second to change the default black notification bar to the hex color I provided in my code. 1 second is not much, so I ignored it.

Recently, I have implemented a splashscreen in my app using the `cordova-splashscreen` plugin; and just like the Cordova v9 doc says, while the splashscreen is being displayed, no JavaScript will run. I've set my splashscreen to disappear after 2 seconds in my `config.xml`.

As a result, the notification bar stays black in color until 2 seconds and only after that does the splashscreen disappear and the bar changes to my specified color. I would really like it to be of the color I specified FROM the app start (like the splashscreen) and not after`deviceready` event.

Is it possible? I'm hoping for some `config.xml` preference such as:-

```
<preference name="StatusBarColor" value="#FFFFFF" />
```

Note that, there exists a preference (somewhat) like this, but only for iOS. I need it for Android.

Comment: no there is nothing such in config https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/config_ref/

Comment: @KhurshidAnsari so this is not possible? please be sure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by editing the `StatusBar.java` file in Cordova plugins folder, and replacing the #000000 launching background color to my desired background color - #FFFFFF.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<preference name="StatusBarBackgroundColor" value="#FFFFFF" />
```

Read the docs [here](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-statusbar/)

Comment: Please add explanation around your code, so that it would be helpful for future readers.

Comment: @Eric Thank you for your answer, but as I said in the last line of my question, this preference only works for iOS and not Android. It seems like the only way to do this on Android is via `StatusBar` API.

Comment: Your post does not reference "StatusBarBackgroundColor"

Comment: @Eric even if it doesn't, the preference still doesn't work in Android. I added the answer that worked.